# JavaScript es2017 Pad Start Object Property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

I am using the `babel env` preset which allows me to use `es2017`. I have tested the `padStart` function on this example:
`'a'.padStart(2, '0')` which yields `0a`. Which is correct and means it's working.

However, when I use it on an object it does not work. `exp_month.padStart(2, '0')` yields `exp_month.padStart is not a function`

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so just worked out that the object property was of type `Integer`. So what I did to resolve the issue was `exp_month.toString().padStart(2, '0')`.